# running from eclipse works perfectly, but from jar, return error JAVA

Tags: java, image, draw

im doing a program to read TIFFs that are named as imagename.00x, where x is the sequence of the page!!

the problem is, running it from the eclipse, it works perfectly, read the directoy, get the files list, show the first and i can use the Previosly and Next button to show another pages..

but when i made the .jar and try to show the image(it works to check if the directoy/number of "Matricula" exist, the problem is when it find and try to draw i think), it return this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java
x.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CL
ibJPEGImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti
on: vendorName == null!
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknow
n Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at certidoesOrganizado.GeraImagem.<init>(GeraImagem.java:25)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui.EnviaLink(gui.java:267)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui.geraListaArquivos(gui.java:233)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui.limpaCaracteres(gui.java:194)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui.confereCaracteres(gui.java:155)
        at certidoesOrganizado.gui$2.actionPerformed(gui.java:77)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        ... more lines
```

the GeraImagem.java where it recieve the PATH to the TIFF file and the screen to edit the labels

```
package certidoesOrganizado;

    import java.awt.*;  
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;  
    import java.io.File;  
    import java.io.IOException;  

    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;  
    import javax.swing.*;  

    public class GeraImagem extends Component {  

        /**   
            *    
            */  
        public static final long serialVersionUID = -6532574194776055714L;  
        Image img;  
        BufferedImage resizedImage = null;  


        public void paint(Graphics g) {  
            g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);  
        }  

        public GeraImagem(String novolink, gui tela) {  
            try {  
                img = ImageIO.read(new File(novolink));  
                img = resizeImage(img, 380, 518);  

                tela.alteraLabel(img);  
            } catch (IOException e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  

        }  

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {  
            if (img == null) {  
                return new Dimension(100, 100);  
            } else {  
                return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));  
            }  
        }  

        // Metodo usado para fazer o resize  
        public Image resizeImage(Image originalImage, int biggerWidth,int biggerHeight) {  
            try {  
                int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;  

                resizedImage = new BufferedImage(biggerWidth, biggerHeight, type);  
                Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();  

                g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);  
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);  
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);  
                g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);  

                g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, biggerWidth, biggerHeight, null);  
                g.dispose();  
            } catch (SecurityException e) {  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao converter imagem!",  
                        "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
            }  
            return resizedImage;  
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Have you compared your command-line class path with your class path in Eclipse? It looks like your command-line run isn't finding a required class.

Comment: Do you use a different version of Java in Eclipse and on the command line, e.g. Oracle JDK in Eclipse and OpenJDK on the command line?

Comment: [This article](https://www.java.net//node/695773) may be helpful.

Comment: Please provide the gui.java class source code.

Comment: @user2582318 - Looks like you are missing required information in your MANIFEST file in your jar.

Comment: @user2582318 - More information can be found at following link:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/packageman.html

Comment: rec no, the same |||
Xabster its big and have seriously errors in java logic(but work in the eclipse), its ugly, but i can post if you want to read and maybe help me =x |||
@chrylis, i cant understand i made another program and it worked fine, and i tested what you said in the LINK
SachinThapa i added some informations(same info as Chrylis, but dont worked, still the same error!! =(((((

Answer (score 2):

**Found the SOLUTION ->**

https://www.servoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13625&p=70765#p70765

just use this jai_imagio.jar, that it fix the problem ;)